# Jquery validation and submit handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation to validate my form, i want to show the submit button when ever the validation rules passed true,

```
$(function(){
    $('.newEmp').validate({ 
         submitHandler: function(){ 
            alert("Submitted!");
         },
         rules:{
             email:{
                 required: true,
                 email: true
             },
             first_name:{
                 required: true,
                 minlength: 4
             },
             last_name:{
                 required: true,
                 minlength: 4                
             },
             mobile:{
                 required: true,
                 minlength: 4                
             },
             position:{
                 required: true,
                 minlength: 4                
             }
         }
    });



});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="blue_button" style="display:none;">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

where should i put this code to show my submit button

`$('.blue_button').css('display', 'block');`

Comment: Is there an option that lets you set a callback for validation passing?

Comment: your form is validated only after you submit the form...so hidding it before doesnot make sense

Comment: so how could i make it validate onfocus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger validation manually with `$('.newEmp').valid()`. Than if it passes, you can show the submit button.

Update:

```
$('.newEmp input').focus(function (){
    if ($('.newEmp').valid()) {
        $('.blue_button').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: See the updated example code. On focus of your input elements (in this case, you can extend the selector) it will validate your form and if everything is valid show the submit button.